# Can we use ip to access admin page instead of login?

Tags: security, ip, ip-address

Let say I have a table in database to save all the ip address that allow to access admin page.
Is that good for security?

Comment: Do you mean in addition to some other security measure, or only based upon the client's IP address?

Comment: Try to use an IP address to go directly to an Admin page. :)

Comment: @davejagoda mainly on IP address. something like this. if (ip==abc) go to admin. else go to index.

Comment: I would recommend against using only IP address to allow access. What prevents an attacker on the same network as one of your administration machines from assigning their machine the same IP address as the administrators'? Augmenting access with a list of registered IP addresses is reasonable, though.